# How does Spring Boot find the controller package?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm studying Spring Boot from a sample project.
It has application like below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PayrollApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and in controller package there is a controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/")
```

And an index.html in template.
I'm still confused in how the run method find the controller package?And at where the index.html is set as default page? Any help? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on configurations(InternalResourceViewResolver is responsible as default if no configurations is done at all, see below the picture) the default behavior of the view resolver is described below(from Pivotal Certified Professional chapter6):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The annotation @Controller allows to auto-detect implementation classes through the classpath scanning.
It tells Spring that your class is a component of type Controller.